# Pandas: How to get rows between indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, rows

Good day everyone.
My problem is: I can't get rows (data) between several rows.
I've got One excel book with 21 sheets. Every table on every sheet with some different changes. Tables haven't heads (people who made it - are idiots). But there are same values in first and second columns in tables. So, i get their indexes, but how to get rows between them?
[image]

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = r"./files/menu.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file_path).sheet_names
breakfast = df.loc[df['Unnamed: 0'] == 'breakfast'].index[0]   # index is "5"
dinner = df.loc[df['Unnamed: 0'] == 'dinner'].index[0]         # index is "14"
heads = df.iloc[[int(breakfast) - 1]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the range `start:end` in the `iloc()` operation to specify start and end indexes. Remember that the start index is included in the result while the end index is excluded:

```
rows_between = df.iloc[int(breakfast)+1:int(dinner)]
```